# What does $\overline{f(E)}$ mean exactly?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, notation

I am prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$.

I am not clear on what $\overline{f(E)}$ is?

Comment: Closure..................

Comment: I know that, I am not clear on what the closure of a function is, or rather I am having trouble conceptualizing (or visualizing the space).

Comment: That's why it's important to offer more context of what you don't understand.

Comment: $\overline{f(E)}$ does not denote the closure of a function. It denotes the closure of a subset of $Y$, namely the subset $f(E)$.

Comment: Your confusion is about what $f(E)$ means. It's important to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:X \to Y$, and $E \subseteq X$, it means the closure of the *set* $f(E) \subseteq Y$

Answer (score 0):

In your case, $\overline{f(E)}$ means the *closure* of $f(E)$, the image of $E$ by $f$.

The closure $\overline F$ of a set $F$, is defined as follow: it is the smallest (in the sens of $\subseteq$) set $G=\overline F$ such that $F\subseteq G$.

It exists since:

$$\overline F=\bigcap_{G\supseteq F\text{ and $G$ is closed}}G.$$

For instance, if $F$ is closed, you cans see that $\overline F=F$.

Answer (score 0):

Given any subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $\bar{A}$ (the *closure* of $A$) is the smallest closed set containing $A$. Equivalently, it is the set of the elements $x\in X$ such that, for every neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, $V \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your tag (real analysis).

The elements of $F(E)$, are in the form $F(x_n)$ given $x_n \in E$.
Suppose $F(x_n)=:y_n$ define a convergent sequence $(y_n)$,  the set $\overline{F(E)}$  is the set of all limits in the form $F(x_n)$.